# Connecting to SQL server using SQL Client and DSN

Tags: sql-server, dsn, sqlclient

Would it be possible to connect to SQL server using DSN however using SqlClient rather than ODBC.

As a matter of fact we have to upgrade a legacy VB6 component however we have to keep the user suitability same ie the users are connecting to database using a DSN.

I would like to avoid ODBC if it would be possible to connect using SqlClient.

Any comments, examples would be appreciated.

ta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the answer is no. Either use ODBC or OLEDB.